# Delphi Metafile Canvas wrong font aspect ratio on Remote Desktop when Screen resolution use non standar setting

Tags: delphi, remote-desktop

I have a project developed using Delphi, using TMetafileCanvas and filling in text on it.
At the standard 1920x1080 screen resolution, text can be displayed normally.
But when using Microsoft's Remote Desktop and using a custom resolution, such as 1920x800.
The width-to-height ratio of the text will change, causing the text spacing to become very small.The greater the difference in screen resolution aspect ratio, the more serious the font distortion will be.

[This picture is a screenshot of the problem when using 1920x800.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioZy5.jpg)

Then I found that when I use the MAC version of Parallels Client (Remote Desktop Client), the obtained VERTSIZE is 212, and the text can be displayed correctly
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWrHi.jpg)

Does anyone know what's causing this? Is there any way to fix this?

Thank you for taking the time to understand my issue, thank you very much.

Source:

```pascal
    unit Unit1;

    interface

    uses
      Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
      Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Button1: TButton;
        imgData1: TImage;
        Button2: TButton;
        Memo1: TMemo;
        ComboBox1: TComboBox;
        ckFix: TCheckBox;
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
        procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
        FMetaFile : TMetafile ;
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form1: TForm1;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      mMetaCanvas: TMetafileCanvas;
      mCanvas: TCanvas;
      mFont : TFont ;
      mHORZSIZE,mVERTSIZE : Integer ;
      LogFont : TLogFont;
      FH1: HFONT;
      mTextHeight, mTextWidth: Integer ;
    const
      str = 'abcdefghijklmopq';
    begin
      mMetaCanvas:= TMetafileCanvas.Create(FMetafile,0);
      mCanvas:= mMetaCanvas;
      mCanvas.Pen.Color:= clwhite;
      mCanvas.Brush.Style:= bsclear;
      mCanvas.Brush.Color:= clwhite;
      mCanvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, imgData1.Width, imgData1.Height));
      mCanvas.Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
      mFont := TFont.Create ;
      mFont.Name := 'Times New Roman' ; //ComboBox1.Text ;
      mFont.Size := 11 ;
      mCanvas.Font.Assign(mFont);

      TextOut(mCanvas.Handle, 50, 50, str, Length(str));
      mMetaCanvas.free;
      imgData1.Picture.Metafile:= FMetafile;
    end;

    procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      HDC : THandle ;
      mHORZSIZE ,mVERTSIZE,mHORZRES,mVERTRES : Integer ;
    begin
      HDC := GetDC(0);
      mHORZSIZE := GetDeviceCaps (HDC, HORZSIZE);
      mVERTSIZE := GetDeviceCaps (HDC, VERTSIZE);

      mHORZRES := GetDeviceCaps (HDC, HORZRES);
      mVERTRES := GetDeviceCaps (HDC, VERTRES);

      Memo1.Lines.Append('HORZSIZE:' + IntToStr(mHORZSIZE)) ;
      Memo1.Lines.Append('VERTSIZE:' + IntToStr(mVERTSIZE)) ;
      Memo1.Lines.Append('HORZRES:' + IntToStr(mHORZRES)) ;
      Memo1.Lines.Append('VERTRES:' + IntToStr(mVERTRES)) ;
    end;

    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      FMetaFile:= TMetafile.Create;
    end;


    end.
```

[This is the source of the project, you can download it from here.](http://gofile.me/6YAxt/XChFmEMKn)

Comment: It's best to post your source here on SO.  I won't download from third party, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, the program code has been attached.